# executeFetchRequest contains "<null>" and my data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

Hello in my ViewController:

```
[super viewDidLoad];

context = [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Items" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if(error){
    NSLog(@"++++++++");
    return;
}

NSLog(@"ARRRAY====%@",[results valueForKey:@"items"]  );
```

And data is:

```
("null>", MyGoodData)
```

If I call this code in AppDelegate all ok.:

And data is:

```
(MyGoodData)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question and format the code so that it's readable as a code block, and also provide good detail so that we can help you better. Also do not forget to search before asking, because many questions have already been asked with good answers. (:

Answer (score 10):

First, your error checking is wrong.  You should be checking for

```
if (results == nil) {
  //Error condition
}
```

Not checking the results of `error`.  `error` can be populated even in a non error condition.

Second, the value of `results` is a `NSArray` which means there is no value for the key `items`. You can just print out the results of the array directly:

```
NSLog(@"ARRAY ==== %@", results);
```

Comment: `error` could be populated in a non-error condition? Do you have a source for that?

Comment: The source is Apple itself.  All methods that accept a `NSError**` have a return value that is to be tested for failure.  Check the documentation for these methods.

Comment: Yes, but do you have a source about the error being populated in a non-error condition?

Comment: The source is my own experience researching during my writing of the book on Core Data and my conversations with the team who wrote Core Data as well as conversations with numerous members of the team who maintain the Cocoa Frameworks.  Ignore the results of the `error` pointer unless you get a failure condition from the method call.  That is the rule in Cocoa and Core Data follows that rule.  The `error` pointer **IS** used as a scratch pad and is not reset back to `nil` and therefore **CAN** be populated even in a successful condition.

Comment: There are, however, explicit exceptions. See for example MKETAHandler (quoting):

This block takes two parameters:

• The response parameter contains the travel time response. If an error occurred or no travel time could be determined, this parameter is nil.

• The error parameter contains information about any errors that occurred. If no errors occurred, this parameter is nil.

The implementation of your block should check for a value in the error parameter and, if that parameter is nil, incorporate the travel-time information provided in the response parameter.

Comment: In case you still want a source, see iOS Developer Library: Error Handling Programming Guide. The first box labeled "Important": https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-BAJIIGCC

Comment: ...though note that in the case of MKETAHandler, checking response == nil would still work OK.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra: I'm confused, in your book you often use `if (error)` without checking the results first.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Items"];
```

`[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Items" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"items > 0"];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"range" ascending:YES];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort, nil]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];`

Answer (score -2):

Solution:

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"items > 0"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense at all.  The `NSArray` will **NEVER** respond to `-valueForKey:@"items"`.

Comment: yes, I can explain this. if valueForkey@"items"!=null than fetchh.
if (results == nil) {} - result !=0.
Problem that when NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; for some reason to array add <null> object.
sorry, but all your offers are wrong. My is working to array not add <null> object
Thanks